# Navbar height is too small after coming back from a landscape view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app with both a tabbar and a navbar.

I load onto my view which has a menu of 3 views. 1 landscape and 2 portrait.

I go onto a portrait view and the navbar is perfect.

[image: view1]

I go into my landscape view and it acts like i want it to.

[image: view2]

When I go back to my portrait view the navbar is now to small.

[image: view3]

When I enter my landscape view this code gets called:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

NSLog(@" viewWillAppear ");
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
appDelegate = (iGeo2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_originalTransform = [[appDelegate tabBarController].view transform];
_originalBounds = [[appDelegate tabBarController].view bounds];
_originalCenter = [[appDelegate tabBarController].view center];

CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +80.0);

[self.tabBarController.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

self.tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.tabBarController.view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
self.tabBarController.view.center  = CGPointMake (240.0, 160.0);
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}
```

Then as I leave my landscape view this code gets called to reset everything:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSLog(@" viewWillDisappear ");

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; 
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[appDelegate tabBarController].view setTransform:_originalTransform];
[[appDelegate tabBarController].view setBounds:_originalBounds];
[[appDelegate tabBarController].view setCenter:_originalCenter];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

}
```

Can anybody advise as to what I need to do to reset the navbar to the correct height?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Set it to hidden and recreate it with your custom buttons in it.

Comment: As a work around that might be ok. Thanks for the idea danipralea. But is there an actual fix to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same Problem with hidden bars and custom buttons. It is not really an answer but a work around. As danipralea mentioned you have to hide them and show them again and it works. Maybe Apple is aware of this issue, but they haven't fixed it yet.

It's not the best but for me it worked…